# Perfect or imperfect for modal verbs?

Tags: modal-verb

Welche Zeitform ist besser:

> Ich habe viel arbeiten müssen.

oder

> Ich musste viel arbeiten?

Ist eine der zwei Formen häufiger?

Comment: Die Antwort von folgender Frage könnte weiterhelfen: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/41320/why-are-some-imperfect-verbs-more-frequently-used-than-perfect

Answer (score 3):

Ich verstehe den Bezug zu Modalverben in der Frage ehrlich gesagt nicht. Warum soll die Anwesenheit eines Modalverbs standardsprachlich einen Unterschied im Tempusgebrauch bewirken? Ich habe von einem solchen Zusammenhang noch nie gehört.

Ganz generell löst die Frage, wann das Präsensperfekt und wann das Präteritum verwendet werden soll, bei Sprechern - Nichtmuttersprachlern ebenso wie Muttersprachlern - erhebliche Unsicherheit aus. Weil es vielen schwerfällt, zwischen den Tempora zu unterscheiden, ist darüber glücklicherweise aber auch schon vieles geschrieben worden. Zum Beispiel hier:

- *IDS/Grammis*, [*Die Vorstellung hat bereits begonnen* oder *Die Vorstellung begann bereits*? — Unterschiede beim Gebrauch von Präteritum und Präsensperfekt](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/fragen/3287)
- *Canoo*, [Das Perfekt](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Tempora/Perfekt.html?MenuId=Word21223)

In Bezug auf Ihren Beispielsatz können Sie den dortigen ausführlichen Erklärungen auch entnehmen, dass zumindest keine der Zeitformen ausgeschlossen sein wird. Eine Präferenz kann sich jedoch aus dem Kontext ergeben. Diesen liefern Sie nicht mit. In einem Zusammenhang wie

- *Ich bin heute schon um fünf Uhr aufgestanden und ins Büro gefahren. Ich habe viel arbeiten müssen. Jetzt bin ich erschöpft.*

würde man standardsprachlich etwa Präsensperfekt bevorzugen, weil das Arbeitenmüssen hier gerade den Zustand in der Sprechzeit *(Jetzt bin ich erschöpft)* bewirkt. Wenn Sie hingegen über Ihre anstrengende Kindheit berichten, wird dieser Bericht typischerweise im Präteritum stehen.

Was die Häufigkeit der beiden Tempora anbetrifft, ist zu konstatieren, dass das Präteritum in der geschriebenen Sprache im Allgemeinen häufiger als das Präsensperfekt auftritt. Siehe *IDS*, op. cit.:

[image]

In der gesprochenen Sprache ist der Gebrauch des Präsensperfekts allerdings häufiger als in der geschriebenen. Zudem gibt es regionale Unterschiede. So haben etwa oberdeutsche Dialekte schon bis Ende des 16. Jahrhunderts einen so genannten [Präteritumschwund](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oberdeutscher_Pr%C3%A4teritumschwund) erfahren; dort sind Präteritalformen daher noch heute zumindest in der gesprochenen Sprache sehr selten. Es wird vermutet, dass sich diese Tendenz zunehmend nordwärts ausbreitet.

Was freilich vermutlich auch richtig ist, ist, dass Sprecher *in der gesprochenen Praxis* gewisse Konstruktionen eher scheuen werden als andere. Insofern ist es gut möglich, dass jemand die Form *habe viel arbeiten müssen* eher zugunsten der präteritalen Alternative zu vermeiden sucht, um nicht noch ein drittes Verb *(haben)* unterbringen zu müssen (Stichwort: Sprachökonomie). Tatsächlich ist etwa auch bekannt, dass eine gewisse Tendenz besteht, komplexe Prädikate eher ins Präteritum zu setzen (dazu *Welke*, Tempus im Deutschen, 2005, S. 340 ff.).

Comment: Je weiter nördlich man kommt, desto mehr Verben werden auch in der gesprochenen Sprache im Präteritum benutzt. Die Modalverben gehören dabei zu den heißesten Kandidaten. Es käme mir z.B. nicht in den Sinn *Ich habe viel arbeiten müssen.* zu sagen. Viel zu kompliziert.

Comment: @Janka und du bist eine nördlichere Person?

Comment: "Ich verstehe den Bezug zu Modalverben in der Frage ehrlich gesagt nicht." In grammar books, I think I have read that there is a distinction as it is said that modal verbs as well as auxiliary verbs tend to be used more with simple past even in the regions where other verbs are more used with present perfect in spoken German. Same idea that these verbs as well as some common irregular verbs are used more in past subjunctive whereas the past subjunctive of most verbs are hardly ever used in everyday speech.

Comment: @Beta: Ich komme aus dem Harzvorland. Hier gibt es ein Gemisch zwischen Westfälisch und Sächsisch. Man nimmt das, was einem näher liegt.

Comment: Yes, the question is based on what we learn in grammar books.  They suggest using the simple of modal verbs because it is complicated than the double infinitive.  I was hoping to find out if that is generally more common in speech or if it was just about simplifying.

Comment: @User The response addresses this. The part that you are quoting refers to the "Welche Zeitform ist besser" part of the question, which refers to rules of (standard) grammar not frequency of use.

Comment: @DawnWilliams, why didn't you write that in your question? It is very frustrating to respond to an extremely broad question only to find out that it could have easily been narrowed down.

Comment: It's quite well-known that in spoken German generally the present perfect is more frequently used than the simple past. However, in case of modal verbs, can we say that they are also more frequently used in speech in present perfect than the simple past? What about auxiliary verbs in spoken German?.. Could you please edit your answer and refer to modal or/and auxiliary verbs whether they constitute a special case in spoken German?

Answer (score 0):

Das Modalverb hat mit *diesem* Unterschied nichts zu tun. Wie immer fokussiert das Imperfekt auf die *Handlung selbst* und das Perfekt auf die *Auswirkung*:

> Ich musste viel arbeiten. Oft war ich schon um 5:00 auf den Beinen und erst um 23:00 im Bett, und an Freitagen...
>
> Ich habe viel arbeiten müssen. Noch heute wache ich regelmässig um 7:00 auf und...

(Modalverben erlauben allerdings eine subtile Unterscheidung zwischen zwei *verschiedenen* Perfekt-Konstruktionen:

> Er hat hart arbeiten müssen. (He's had to work hard.)
>
> Er muss viel gearbeitet haben. (He must have worked hard.)

Im Gegensatz zur Perfekt/Imperfekt-Unterscheidung wie von johnl beschrieben variiert diese Unterscheidung m.W. auch nicht regional.)

Comment: Why do you translate the first sentence with > He's had to work hard?  Wouldn't that be >Er hatte hart arbeiten müssen?  I would translate the first sentence as >He had to work hard.

Comment: @DawnWilliams for good reasons, because it would be preterite / simple past in both languages: *had to work*--*musste arbeiten*; Whereas *hat müssen* is a perfect formation with Ersatz-infinitive (i.e. "müssen") prefered over the regulalrly correct participle "gemusst". I suppose "has had" is in the perfect as well; and the details are possibly interesting when "have to" is taken into account and compared to the modal Ersatz-Infinitiv, but the details however would be off-topic, here.